# Fetching strings (or other variables) from a CoreData fetch request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have Core Data setup in my app and need to fetch a bunch of items and then access the properties I choose of those fetched items. I am able to successfully fetch a bunch of results like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TableInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This gives me an array with my results, great. Now from this how can I for example get the 'name' property from these results? In this specific circumstance I want to load an array with all of the fetched results 'name' strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are able to fetch your `NSManagedObjects` without difficulty, but would like to derive another `NSArray` with `name` properties on those managed objects?

Then you can use the `valueForKeyPath` on the `NSArray` (extending your original code):

```
NSArray *names = [result valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

Comment: Huzzah! Thanks, couldn't have been easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key-value:

```
for (NSManagedObject *fetchedResult in result) {
    NSLog(@"name = %@", [fetchedResult valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

or if you created your custom NSManagedObject:

```
for (EntityObject *fetchedResult in result) {
    NSLog(@"name = %@", [fetchedResult name]);
}
```